# Convert datetime object to date and datetime2 to time then combine to single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset where the transaction date is stored as YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 and the transaction time is stored as 1900-01-01 HH:MM:SS

I need to truncate these timestamps and then either leave as is or convert to a singular timestamp. I've tried several methods and all continue to return the full timestamp. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` and `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TransDate':['2015-01-01 00:00:00','2015-01-02 00:00:00','2015-01-03 00:00:00'],
                   'TransTime':['1900-01-01 07:00:00','1900-01-01 08:30:00','1900-01-01 09:45:15']})

df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['TransDate'].str.split().str[0] + 
              ' ' +
              df['TransTime'].str.split().str[1]))
```

Output:

```
             TransDate            TransTime                Date
0  2015-01-01 00:00:00  1900-01-01 07:00:00 2015-01-01 07:00:00
1  2015-01-02 00:00:00  1900-01-01 08:30:00 2015-01-02 08:30:00
2  2015-01-03 00:00:00  1900-01-01 09:45:15 2015-01-03 09:45:15

print(df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
TransDate    3 non-null object
TransTime    3 non-null object
Date         3 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
None
```

Comment: Thank you, once I converted them to strings it worked perfectly

Comment: @user1530313 You are welcome.  Glad I could help.  Happy coding.